# Converting serialized data to specific array structure

Tags: php, arrays

I have written some seemingly over-complex code to convert serialized data into a row based array that in turn drives a graphics plug in for a sales reporting ledger. The database queries cannot be changed. Nor can the forms feeding the databases (Both are legacy). So we must work with outputs presented by existing databse select queries. The code Ive written (below) works ok but looks terribly complex. Anyone come up with ideas for a more efficient method?

```
                 //Database Select Queries generating one pair of month-cost rows for each property
                    $cost_amount_array[]=$row->cost_amount; //always a cost value and month returned by form
                    $cost_month_array[]=$row->cost_month;

                  //Serialized data outputs
                    $cost_amount_array[$p] =  [cost_amount] => a:6:{i:0;s:3:"333";i:1;s:3:"111";i:2;s:3:"100";i:3;s:3:"200";i:4;s:3:"690";i:5;s:3:"777";}
                    $cost_month_array[$p]) =  [cost_month] => a:6:{i:0;s:1:"9";i:1;s:2:"10";i:2;s:1:"8";i:3;s:1:"7";i:4;s:1:"6";i:5;s:1:"9";}

          //Final Output Required: Feeds a grahic plug API....
                array 
                (
                array (month1, cost_amount 1) where the cost_amounts need to be summed due multiple if there are multiple form entries for a month 
                array (month2, cost_amount2)
                etc
                etc
                )
```

Routine for producing the Final Array.

```
   //Count the property entries in the $finance_array (output array). 
   //For each property unserialize the (synchronised) month - cost data and put data into a temp array

                for ($p=0; $p<$count_finance_array; $p++) //for each record in array
                {
                    $list_count=count( unserialize($cost_type_array[$p]) ) +$list_count; //grab the number of cost entries and cumulatively count them
                    $C[]=unserialize($cost_amount_array[$p]);
                    $D[]=unserialize($cost_month_array[$p]);
                }

               //Remove top level array wrapper
                    foreach($C as $array){    
                        foreach($array as $key=>$value){
                            //echo "KEY:".$key;
                            //echo "VAL:".$value;
                            $cost_amount_out[]=(int)$value;
                        }
                    } 

                    foreach($D as $array){    
                        foreach($array as $key=>$value){
                            //echo "KEY:".$key;
                            //echo "VAL:".$value;
                            $cost_month_out[]=$value;
                        }
                    } 


      //Remove duplicate months and add up the corresponding cost values if a connected month with a cost-value is duplicated hence deleted

                    $month_cost_row = array_unique($cost_month_out);//returns just the unique values
                    $month_cost_row = array_combine($month_cost_row, array_fill(0, count($month_cost_row), 0));//

                    foreach($cost_month_out as $k=>$v) {
                      $month_cost_row[$v] += (int)$cost_amount_out[$k];
                    }

            //Make the key - which are the months - become the first values of each sub array (ie first value in each month/cost_value row)
                    $month_cost_row_sorted = array_map
                    (function($k, $v) 
                    {
                    return array($k, $v); 
                    }, 
                    array_keys ($month_cost_row), $month_cost_row
                    );

             //Sort the rows by first value ie month (numerically ascend)
                    usort($month_cost_row_sorted, "cmp");
                    //print "<pre>";
                    //print_r($month_cost_row_sorted);
                    //print "</pre>";   

                    function cmp($X, $Y) {
                    return $X[0] - $Y[0];
                    }   
                        //print "<pre>";
                        //print_r($month_cost_row_sorted);
                        //print "</pre>";
```

That routine produces the array format needed. But it is so complex. Can it be simplified?

ps The $p is a count of the rows in the database each row representing a property. All the cost and income data form-side is serialized - so for every ledger there is only one property instance per property rather than hundreds (ie one row per cost entry.), The serialization by property row  is where the complexity on the output side arises. But from a maintenance perspective it makes life much easier - to add new cost or income lines etc is an option addition on a drop down box. Same on the income side which again is just an extension of each property row with serialized property incomes. There is also (for every ledger) a row for general overheads. So a ledger might by 4 rows (one per each of 4 property with serialized income and costs) plus a general row for costs not attributable to a specific property. A ledger is an internal word for an analysis of profitability for groups of properties.

Comment: What does `$p` represent?

Comment: I have extended my question to answer your question sir

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach($rows as $row)
    $out[$row->cost_month] += $row->cost_amount;
ksort($out);
foreach($out as $k=>$v)
    $result[] = [$k, $v];
```

Comment: Thanks. I m not quite sure how this would work. What is the array $rows in relation to the procedure the code i have posted covers?

Comment: @jimshot, the `$rows` represent the database select loop at the beginning of your code.